# How to sort complex datamodel with JPA specification?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following datamodel:

```
+-------------------------+
| Newsletter              |
+-------------------------+
| Long id                |
| String title           |
| Category category      |
| Set<User> users        |
+-------------------------+

+-------------------------+
| Category               |
+-------------------------+
| Long id                |
| String title           |
| List<UserConfig> cfgs  |
+-------------------------+

+-------------------------+
| UserConfig              |
+-------------------------+
| Long id                |
| Category category      |
| User user              |
| boolean visible        |
+-------------------------+

+-------------------------+
| User                   |
+-------------------------+
| Long id                |
| String name            |
+-------------------------+
```

> Newsletter MANY-TO-MANY User (uni-directional)
>
> Newsletter MANY-TO-ONE Category (uni-directional)
>
> Category ONE-TO-MANY UserConfig (bi-directional)
>
> UserConfig MANY-TO-ONE User (uni-directional)

Each newsletter has one category, it can be assigned to multiple users.
Each user can configure for himself whether the category should be visible or not.

I would like to filter and sort for various properties, but doing it for the visible property seems to be rather difficult because of the datamodel.

**Explanation**: I would like to retrieve all newsletter for a specific user, with it, the category title, all the other usernames that receive that newsletter and whether the category for this specific user is visible or not.

To filter, I created a method: `searchNewsletters(Specification<Newsletter> s, Pageable p)`

Because sorting on joined tables with Pageable is rather difficult (in this case impossible for visible property or usernames) I am using JPA spec also for sorting.

```
public static Specification<Newsletter> withSortProperty(String sortProperty, Sort.Direction sortDirection, String userId) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
      switch (sortProperty) {
        case ...
        case UserConfig_.VISIBLE:
         /* HOW ? */
        default: ...
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

The things I tried always return duplicate records. I am always filtering for a specific user, so maybe I can use this in some way, by passing a certain userId to the sort method.
But these tries also failed:

```
public static Specification<Newsletter> withSortProperty(String sortProperty, Sort.Direction sortDirection, String userId) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
      switch (sortProperty) {
        case ...
        case UserConfig_.VISIBLE:
         Join<Newsletter, Category> cj = root.join(Newsletter.category);
      Join<Category, UserConfig> configJoin = cj.join(Category_.configs);
      Join<UserConfig, User> rj = configJoin.join(UserConfig.user);

      Predicate idPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(rj.get(User_.ID), id);
      query.where(idPredicate );

      query.orderBy(sortDirection == Sort.Direction.DESC
          ? criteriaBuilder.desc(configJoin.get(UserConfig.visible))
          : criteriaBuilder.asc(configJoin.get(UserConfig.visible)));
        default: ...
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

Is this even possible? Should I re-think my datamodel? I could sort in memory instead but I really would like to sort in the DB if possible.